# Code to email one page from word using submit button

Tags: vba

I would like to send the last page of a word document (162 pages long) using email. Currently I can send the whole document, but would like the last page  that has the submit button to be the only thing sent.

I have tried changing the name to pge etc. I have little experience.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim OL As Object
Dim EmailItem As Object
Dim Doc As Document

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = ActiveDocument

Doc.Save

With EmailItem
    .Subject = "Insert Subject Here"
    .Body = "I just want this to work already!!"
    .To = "fakeemail@Idonotknowcode.ca"
    .Importance = olImportanceNormal 'Or olImprotanceHigh Or olImprotanceLow
    .Attachments.Add Doc.FullName
    .Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Set Doc = Nothing
Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.builtindocumentproperties) will get you the number of pages then you can just print that.

Comment: I am confused by the above comment. I do not want to print anything, just attach the last page of a multi-page document as it's own attachment to the email. Instead of 162 pages, just the last page.

Comment: Print to pdf...

Comment: What I want to achieve is when someone opens a document and clicks on the submit button it will send the last page as an email. Basically we need people to sign the document and we want the signed page sent back to us, not the whole document as it will bog down our email.

Comment: Right. So determine the last page and print that to pdf then attach to email.